# Asignar valor a div ocultos

Tags: php, javascript, css

soy novata y aprendiendo cosas nuevas, quisiera que me ayudaran a solucionar mi problema, estoy trabajando con 3 radiobutton diferentes y al seleccionar cierto radio aparece un div oculto:

los radiobutton se llaman asi:

- pago_mensual: si selecciono si aparece un div oculto con un input text donde agrego un monto.
- contribuciones: si selecciono si aparece un div oculto con un input text donde agrego un monto.
- pagos_contables: si selecciono si aparece un div oculto con un input text donde agrego un monto.

y obviamente obtengo el total de todos los montos.  Mi problema surge en que si a todos los radio le pongo si y agrego el monto que me SUME y si oculto cualquier div me RESTE al total final.

Los div ocultos no tengo problemas en mostrarlos y ocultarlos, reconocen el llamado, lo que hacen caso es en sumar y restar. Pienso que es algo muy tonto lo que no puedo hacer, estoy trabajando con javascript y php.
Ayuda en como poder hacerlo por favor.

Agrego código de lo que tengo

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
 $('input:radio[name=pago_mensual]').change(function (){
  if($(this).val()==1){
   $("#capa1").show();
  }else{
   $("#capa1").hide();
  }
 });
 
 $('input:radio[name=contri]').change(function (){
  if($(this).val()==1){
   $("#capa2").show();
  }else{
   $("#capa2").hide();
  }
 });
 
 $('input:radio[name=conta]').change(function (){
  if($(this).val()==1){
   $("#capa3").show();
  }else{
   $("#capa3").hide();
  }
 });
 
 function resultadoFinal(){
  tot=document.getElementById('total');
  pag1=document.getElementById('pago1');
  pag2=document.getElementById('pago2');
  pag3=document.getElementById('pago3');
 }
});
</script>
```

```html
<body >

<form>
<div>
Pago Mensual
<input type="radio" name="pago_mensual"  value="1" />Si
<input type="radio" name="pago_mensual"  value="0"  />No
<div id="capa1" style="display:none;">
 Monto Aporte
    <input id="pago1" name="pago1" type="text"  value="<?php $pago1?>"/>
</div> 
</div>
<div>        
Contribuciones
<input type="radio" name="contri"  value="1" />Si
<input type="radio" name="contri"  value="0"  />No
<div id="capa2" style="display:none;">
 Monto Aporte
    <input id="pago2" name="pago2" type="text"  value="<?php $pago2?>"/>
</div> 
</div>
<div>  
Pago Contable
<input type="radio" name="conta"  value="1" />Si
<input type="radio" name="conta"  value="0"  />No
<div id="capa3" style="display:none;">
 Monto Aporte
    <input id="pago3" name="pago3" type="text"  value="<?php $pago3?>"/>
</div>  
</div>
<div> 
Total: <input id="total" name="total" type="text"  value="<?php $total?>"/>    
</div>       
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Pon tu código que lo veamos y rehaz la pregunta. Así no queda muy claro que quieres ni que tienes hecho

Comment: **Es importante que leas [ask]**, deberías de mostrar el código que estás usando o que has intentado y decir si el sistema te arroja errores

Comment: ¿Dónde le asignas un valor a las variables `$pago1`, `$pago2`, `$pago3` y `$total`?

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución es ejecutar una funcion que sume cada vez que escribas en los inputs, y tambien ejecutar esa funcion cuando se oculta un div.

```
$('.input-suma').keyup(function(){
  sumar();
});

function sumar(){
  var suma = 0;
  $('.input-suma').each(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':visible') ){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if( !$(this).val() ) { val = 0 };
        suma = suma + parseInt( val );
    }
  });
  $('#total').val(suma); 
}
```

Después de cada que ejecutas hide() debes llamar a sumar() que solo suma los inputs que están visibles. En mi caso a los tres inputs a sumar les he añadido la clase .input-suma, así no suma el input del total.

Aqui va mi solución al problema : https://jsfiddle.net/FerB/ecf1nj8g/11/
Si no lo he entendido mal.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, voy a editar la respuesta.

Comment: Puedes añadir tu código del jsFiddle al snippet de la comunidad así no te preocuparas por que desaparezca ;). Aparece al lado derecho de insertar la imagen en la barra de herramientas del textArea summernote o como quieras llamarlo ^^

Answer (score 0):

En el evento change de jquery tienes la forma de disparar un listener,

```
$("#tuID").on("change",function(){
   console.log(this.val);

});
```

ahora bien para manipular el value del input oculto lo haces tambien con jquery de la siguiente manera `$("#tuInputOculto").val();`, tener en cuenta que si el div tiene algun input relacionado le cambias es al input interno que puede ser hidden en el div; posteriomente cuando la function que te hace la sumatoria de valores el valor del div al no tener un contenido para sumar te brindará la sumatoria de forma adecuada. Saludos.

Comment: No hay que usar obligatoriamente jQuery para eso, de hecho, la pregunta ni siquiera tiene la etiqueta de jQuery, no entiendo por qué respondes entonces con jQuery.

Comment: Es verdad no necesariamente se requiere jquery, sobre la inquietud planteada, brindo una alternativa ya que javascript puede generarle inconvenientes a futuro con cambios de navegadores... existen otras alternativas y la idea con mi rpta es brindar una forma alternativa para dar solución a lo que se pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que llamar a una función que compruebe cada radio button, y si su estilo visibility es hidden no lo suma (o lo resta), y si está en visible, entonces lo suma.

Por ejemplo:

```
function calcularValores() {
var radio1 = document.getElementById("radio_button1");
var radio2 = document.getElementById("radio_button2");
var radio3 = document.getElementById("radio_button3");

var suma_total = 0;

if (radio1.style.visibility == "visible") {
suma_total = suma_total + (lo que tenga que sumar);
}

if (radio2.style.visibility == "visible") {
suma_total = suma_total + (lo que tenga que sumar);
}

...
```

También lo podrías hacer más correctamente comprobando el value que tenga cada radio button, tendrá el value del radio que esté seleccionado. Entonces haces unas cosas u otras dependiendo de su valor.

Y por último, muestras el valor total donde quieras que se muestre.

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo el código que has pasado y retocando algunos elementos te he montado el javaScript para que sea "más simple" del que tienes (aunque con un selector que no me gusta nada, pero que te servirá) para realizar lo que estás intentando.

> He puesto datos a fuego en el snippet para que se viera a simple
>   vista.

- Se han añadido clases a el **div** oculto y al **input** que contiene para poner realizar una busqueda de elemento más facil.
- Se ha añadido la misma clase para todo los radios **buttons** y así poder tratarlo en una solo función **js** simplificada.

La función realiza dos acciones simples: Muestra o oculta el div según la selección del **radio button** y suma o resta el valor del **input** monto del **radio button** seleccionado.

> **EDIT**

Se ha modificado los errores que tenia al principio, se han marcado también por defecto los radio buttons a "No" para impedir que al seleccionar no la primera vez te restara el valor (Por no pensar escribir más).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pagos").change(function() {    
    var inputMonto = $(this).parent().find(">.montoDiv").find(">.pago");
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
      $("#total").val(parseFloat($("#total").val())+parseFloat(inputMonto.val()));
      inputMonto.parent().show();
    } else {
      inputMonto.parent().hide();
      $("#total").val(parseFloat($("#total").val())-parseFloat(inputMonto.val()));
}
  });
    $(".pago").focus(function() {
     $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
  });
  $(".pago").change(function() {      
     var hola = parseFloat($("#total").val())-parseFloat($(this).data().val);
     $("#total").val(hola);
     $("#total").val(parseFloat($("#total").val())+parseFloat($(this).val()));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    Pago Mensual
    <input type="radio" name="pago_mensual" class="pagos" value="1" />Si
    <input type="radio" name="pago_mensual" class="pagos" value="0" checked />No
    <div id="capa1" class="montoDiv" style="display:none;">
      Monto Aporte
      <input id="pago1" class="pago" name="pago1" type="text" value="50.66" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Contribuciones
    <input type="radio" name="contri" class="pagos" value="1" />Si
    <input type="radio" name="contri" class="pagos" value="0" checked />No
    <div id="capa2" class="montoDiv" style="display:none;">
      Monto Aporte
      <input id="pago2" class="pago" name="pago2" type="text" value="100" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Pago Contable
    <input type="radio" name="conta" class="pagos" value="1" />Si
    <input type="radio" name="conta" class="pagos" value="0" checked/>No
    <div id="capa3" class="montoDiv" style="display:none;">
      Monto Aporte
      <input id="pago3" class="pago" name="pago3" type="text" value="33.05" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Total: <input id="total" name="total" type="text" value="0.0" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Estoy modificando el js para que al modificar el monto también cambie el total